# ¿ Como importar certificados de confianza de OpenSSL en Windows 10?

Tags: nodejs, windows10, certificado-ssl, certificado, localhost

Hola estoy tratando de importar un certificado de confianza de openSSl para localhost donde tengo un servidor Express.
He visto opciones de hacerlo en Mac,que es Keychain Access, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo desde windows 10.
Quisiera saber que carpeta es en Windows 10 y la forma de acceder desde la consola y si tiene parte de interfaz.
Gracias.

Comment: No relacionado con tu pregunta en sí, pero creo que [esta otra publicación puede interesarte](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/169491/250) porque seguramente sepas la respuesta (parece que intentan hacer algo que has debido completar para llegar al punto de tu pregunta).