# ¿Cómo instalar OpenSSL en windows 10?

Tags: windows10, openssl

Tengo una duda de cómo y cuál es la versión de OpenSSl que debo instalar en Windows  para luego poder crear certificados.

Instalé una versión (openssl-1.0.2d-fips-2.0.10) encontrada en source-force pero no me genera los archivos correctamente. También esta la [página oficial](https://www.openssl.org), pero no sé cuál instalar y cómo, para que a la hora de generar las llaves y archivo .pem, funcione.

Generé unas variables de entorno que apuntan a la carpeta donde descomprimí lo descargado, no sé si es la manera correcta.

> EDITO: para ampliar detalles.

Esta fue la forma en que Instale la version que comento de openssl: en la carpeta creada para poner los archivos, saque los archivo de la carpeta bin a la carpeta principal.
De ahi, cree dos variables de entorno, una en variables del usuario apuntando a la carpeta de openssl.
Cree otra variable en "**variables de sistema**, añadiéndola a path, también apuntando a openssl.
Si pienso que no funciona es porque los archivos generados con `openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem` me generan archivos sin llave. 
Cuando digo llave es que no tienen el logotipo, o como quiera que se llame la marca como la siguiente captura, la cual obtuve de un ejemplo de llave o certificado.
Espero con esto explicarme para que puedan ayudarme.
Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podes probar con https://www.cygwin.com/ (elegir el paquete net/red en la instalación) que trae el openssl para windows

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy parecida (o la misma) a otra realizada hace apenas unas horas. ¿Es parte de una clase o algo?

Comment: Estoy siguiendo un curso @AlvaroMontoro . Pues busque por el sitio para guiarme  y no encontré nada parecido. He vuelto a buscar, y no encuentro nada sobre _instalar openSSL en windows_

Comment: Me refiero a esta pregunta [¿ Como importar certificados de confianza de OpenSSL en Windows 10?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/169479/250). Releyendo, no son lo mismo, pero se parecen bastante... Y diría que Mari Cruz va un paso por delante en la tarea :P

Comment: Pues ya podía responder a mi pregunta porque llevo días buscando la forma sin éxito, gracias @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Le dejo un mensaje a ver si se anima a responder y te echa un cable.

Comment: Relacionado con tu pregunta, deberías editar la publicación para añadir algo más de información porque tal y como está redactada ahora es algo amplia: ¿qué pasos sigues para instalar OpenSSL en tu ordenador? ¿cómo sabes que no se ha instalado correctamente o que genera las llaves mal? (¿recibes algún error? ¿qué pasos sigues para crear las llaves?) ¿Es eso un problema al instalar OpenSSL o al generar las llaves?

Comment: Pero entonces  parece que el problema no es que el certificado no se genere bien, sino que tienes que instalar el certificado en el almacén de certificados de confianza (que sería el mismo problema que expone Mari Cruz en su pregunta). ¿O me estoy perdiendo algo?

Comment: Los archivos que a se me generan, no son como el que muestro en la captura, porque al pinchar en ellos debería de dar la apariencia que muestra la imagen, y no es así, no me dan la posibilidad de instalarlos. Lo cual, no estarán bien generados, o no instale correctamente openSSl porque todo lo que ley es que openSSL no tiene Binarios para windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo saque los binarios para Windows de la siguiente pagina: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries
Hay varias opciones, yo elegí la primera.
De no funcionar puedes probar las siguientes opciones.
Instale en C/: pero fuera del directorio donde están los archivos de Windows siguiendo los consejos de un tutorial.
También cree las variables de entorno apuntando a la carpeta generada.
Para probar si instalo correctamente, colocas openssl en consola, y debería de entrar en OPENSSL.
Lo que ya no tengo yo claro es de como importar los certificados que generas, pues mis archivos no son como los que tu muestras.
Espero te ayude, si es así, el culpable y al que debes agradecer es @AlvaroMontoro que me comunico tu pregunta.